# How to add multiple mysql data generated my user in single row?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a website where user can enter his/her academic data. In this case, user can add additional projects and other work he/she has done in his/her academic year. For Example, I have given some form fields to enter year, topic and description of project on user profile page. But by clicking Add more button, another HTML form appears where user can add another project details. User can add as much projects as he/she wants.

But when it comes to storage in database, it is difficult to store this data into single row because MySQL does not expand horizontally. But I am creating different table `projects` then it would be very difficult to manage the table and table would be really big. Is there any alternative way to efficiently store this kind of data where a single row for user can add as many columns as user enter projects?

Comment: Can you show pls your database model or entity relationship model to show relationsships and what you want to store. I think it's just an model issue.

Comment: It's easier to maintain two tables with 1:n relationship than it is maintaining one gigantic text field which contains all projects of a single person. If all the projects are from a predefined curriculum you can use a look up table and you need 1:n relationship only for the comments/extra info (and an intermediate table between projects and persons). Otherwise just add a new row for each project into `projects` table and link that row to `person` table.

Comment: Just made an Edit to the answer concerning performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the following model

```
Table Student
--------------------
ID | name    | ... | ...
--------------------
1 | Jon Doe  | ... | ...


Table Project
---------------------------------------------------------
ID | name     | description | var1    | var2 | Student_ID /Foreign Key to Student Table
---------------------------------------------------------     
 2 | project1 | a project   | physics | .... |    1 
 3 | project2 | another pro | IT      | .... |    1   
 . |     .    |     .       |    .    | .... |    -
```

The given model shows a one to many relationship between student and project. 
The Foreign Key is Student_ID and is associated with the primary key of the Student table.
This enables you to store n projects with one student.

Try to normalize your database model. Means everytime redundant data seems to occure think about to create a new table and a specific relationship.

Alternatively to the one to many relationship i am showing in the example you can 
model a many to many relationship which enables you to store one student with n projects and one project with associations to n students.

EDIT Performance issues

One comment to performance. It is important to create indices for the columns which are mostly queried by the where clause of a select statement. An index is a special datastructure (generally a Tree but it really depends on the DBMS) which enables the database system to perform database queries in a
effectiv way. So if you query for student names for example create an addiontional index
on the name column.

For Foreign Key relationships the dbms automatically creates an appropriate index.

Furthermore i don't think that you will run into performance issues with your project.
MySQL can handle millions of rows pretty well.
This means not that mass data won't lead to performance issues in general. And it really depends on the DBMS how it handles mass data.

```
 .       .          .           .         .        .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a separate table to hold the dynamic projects. Then link each row in that table to the user by Userid or some other unique value.. Basically what you need to do is use the userid in the projects table as an identifier to link each item to the corresponding user.. By doing this you can have a one to many relationship.

Comment: What do you think about the table size? As it could have millions of rows.. Would it hamper the performance of the table?

Comment: That wont matter too much. As a `select * from yourtablename where userid = 'whateverid';` will work pretty quickly and shouldn't be much of a performance issue. Its not a complex query so I think you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table, name it "projects" (or whatever) and store all projects' details with a "student ID" coloumn.. Like following:

Student ID | Project ID | Project Details 1 | Project Details 2

Now, for a indiviual "Student ID", you can retrieve details of all the projects that he has entered.